# Use of grep + sed based on a pattern file?

Tags: regex, sed, grep

Here's the problem: i have ~35k files that might or might not contain one or more of the strings in a list of 300 lines containing a regex each

if I `grep -rnwl 'C:\out\' --include=*.txt -E --file='comp.log'` i see there are a few thousands of files that contain a match.

now how do i get sed to delete each line in these files containing the strings in comp.log used before?

edit: comp.log contains a simple regex in each line, but for the most part each string to be matched is unique

this is is an example of how it is structured:

```
server[0-9]\/files\/bobba fett.stw
[a-z]+ mochaccino
[2-9] CheeseCakes
...
```

etc. silly examples aside, it goes to show each line is unique save for a few variations so it shouldn't affect what i really want: see if any of these lines match the lines in the file being worked on. it's no different than 's/pattern/replacement/' except that i want to use the patterns in the file instead of inline.

---

Ok here's an update (S.O. gets inpatient if i don't declare the question answered after a few days)
after MUCH fiddling with the @Kenavoz/@Fischer approach, i found a totally different solution, but first things first.
creating a modified pattern list for sed to work with **does** work.

as well as @werkritter's approach of dropping sed altogether. (this one i find the most... err... "least convoluted" way around the problem).

I couldn't make @Mklement's answer work under windows/cygwin (it did work on under ubuntu, so...not sure what that means. figures.)

What ended up solving the problem in a more... long term, reusable form was a wonderful program pointed out by a colleage called [PowerGrep](http://www.powergrep.com/). it really blows every other option out of the water. unfortunately it's windows only AND it's not free. (not even advertising here, the thing is not cheap, but it does solve the problem).

so considering @werkiter's reply was not a "proper" answer and i can't just choose both @Lars Fischer and @Kenavoz's answer as a solution (they complement each other), i am awarding @Kenavoz the tickmark for being first.

final thoughts: i was hoping for a simpler, universal and free solution but apparently there is not.

Comment: What is `'C:\out\'`? Are you on a Windows/DOS machine?

Comment: or could i just pass the file path and line number from grep instead of having to compare with the pattern file...again?

Comment: yes, it's windows but if i open mintty instead of cmd, it looks different, so i don't think it's relevant. "c:\out" is the path where all the files to be changed reside.

Comment: Could you add an example of some lines in comp.log, some unique and some repeated? I would usually give gnu sort with the `-u` unique option a try, if sorting is possible.

Comment: yes, please add sample text from your log file along with keyword you want to find and delete corresponding lines.

Comment: @LarsFischer , comp.log is a comparison file with one simple match per line such as:
server[0-9]/files/boba fett

Comment: @VileTouch Sorry, but I still dont understand the problem. Could you please give more details where you want to remove *something*? In the comp.log or in the output of grep? And what do you want to remove: filenames, regexes or the matched strings?

Comment: @LarsFischer: ah ok. comp.log is a list of patterns to be matched by grep and sed. the files to be edited reside in c:\out as the grep command shows. there is no replacement string, i just want to delete the lines (in the 35k files) that match my list of patterns.

Comment: I see a problem with using `sed` in this case, depending of what version you use: namely, I see that you use `-E` and `-w` switches with `grep`. Do you really wish the contents of `comp.log` to be treated as ERE patterns and to match whole words? If so, and if you don't use GNU `sed`, you can't really accomplish your task with `sed` without rewriting the contents of `comp.log`.

Comment: @wekritter: aah good eye :)  yes, the choice of ERE is so i don't have to deal with BRE treating my slashes and dots differently than just part of the string. (though i still have some escaped slashes there [shrugs]).
the -w switch is there because it was catching some unwanted stuff (which doesn't happen with -w ). the -n is there just as a test (so i know how many matches there are).

Comment: The only way I know of using ERE with `sed` is to have a GNU version and use the `-r` switch. Unfortunately, there's no `-w` equivalent, so you either adjust your pattern file to match proper lines without the switch — or find a way to solve your task without using `sed`.

Comment: Due to the above, I believe the answers proposed so far, based on transforming the pattern file into a sed commands file, won't work properly.

Comment: I'd propose a different approach: you can use the `grep` output to find out which lines have to be removed from each file and remove them automatically. If you run `grep -ErHn 'C:\out\' --include=*.txt -E --file='comp.log' | cut -f1-2 -d: | uniq`, you'll get an output on which you can work programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
sed -f <(sed 's/^/\//g;s/$/\/d/g' comp.log) file > outputfile
```

All regex in `comp.log` are formatted to a sed address with a `d` command : `/regex/d`. This command deletes lines matching the patterns.

This internal sed is sent as a file (with [process substitition](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)) to the `-f` option of the external sed applied to `file`.

To delete just string matching the patterns (not all line) :

```
sed -f <(sed 's/^/s\//g;s/$/\/\/g/g' comp.log) file > outputfile
```

**Update :**

The command output is redirected to `outputfile`.

Comment: wait, if i understand correctly, your output file is comp.log
that;s not the file i want to be edited, that;s the list of strings to match in the files, effectively what (i assume) is your regexlist.

however, you seem to have used sed within sed to output a temp file that contains...one line?

Comment: Updated. Internal sed transform your regex file to sed formatted patterns. With process substitution, it's uses as a regular regex file applied to `file`.

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas but not a complete solution, as it requires some adopting to your script (not shown in the question).

1. I would convert comp.log into a sed script containing the necessary deletes:

   ```
   cat comp.log | sed -r "s+(.*)+/\1/ d;+" > comp.sed`
   ```

   That would make your example comp.sed look like:

   ```
   /server[0-9]\/files\/bobba fett.stw/ d;
   /[a-z]+ mochaccino/ d;
   /[2-9] CheeseCakes/ d;
   ```
2. then I would apply the `comp.sed` script to each file reported by grep (With your `-rnwl` that would require some filtering to get the filename.):

   ```
   sed -i.bak -f comp.sed $AFileReportedByGrep
   ```

   If you have gnu sed, you can use `-i` inplace replacement creating a .bak backup, otherwise use piping to a temporary file

Comment: That's a [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) but good comments in general.

Comment: well, there is no script. I started with a .bat file with a for loop and ditched it in favor of grep as it was too slow and inefficient so what you see is all there is.

yes, my sed accepts the -i parameter, i guess that's what cygwin comes with.

Comment: @Kenavoz I answered after the discussion below the question gave me the insight that VileTouch wants two things from one list of regex: get the filename with matches (the grep part) and delete lines (the sed part). I answered after reading the comment that your answer did not work as VileTouch expected (and (believe me or not) without further understanding what you answered). But you are right both answers express the idea of adopting the list of regex into a sed script.

Comment: ok, I'm trying both of you great minds's solution... will be back shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Both [Kenavoz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36248489/45375) and [Lars Fischer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36249308/45375) use the same ingenious approach:
transform the list of input regexes into a list of `sed` match-and-delete commands, passed as a file acting as the script to `sed` via `-f`.

To complement these answers with a single command that puts it all together, assuming you have *GNU* `sed` and your shell is `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh` (to support `<(...)`):

```
find 'c:/out' -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i -r -f <(sed 's#.*#/\\<&\\>/d#' comp.log) {} +
```

- `find 'c:/out' -name '*.txt'` matches all `*.txt` files in the subtree of dir. `c:/out`

  - `-exec ... +` passes as many matching files as will fit on a single command line to the specified command, typically resulting only in a *single* invocation.
- `sed -i` updates the input files *in-place* (conceptually speaking - there are caveats); append a suffix (e.g., `-i.bak`) to save backups of the original files with that suffix.
- `sed -r` activates support for *extended* regular expressions, which is what the input regexes are.
- `sed -f` reads the script to execute from the specified filename, which in this case, as explained in [Kenavoz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36248489/45375), uses a process substitution (`<(...)`) to make the enclosed `sed` command's output act like a [transient] file.

  - The `s///` `sed` command - which uses alternative delimiter `#` to facilitate use of *literal* `/` - encloses each line from `comp.log` in `/\<...\>/d` to yield the desired deletion command; the enclosing of the input regex in `\<...\>`ensures matching as a *word*, as `grep -w` does.
    This is the primary reason why *GNU* `sed` is required, because neither POSIX EREs (extended regular expressions) nor BSD/OSX `sed` support `\<` and `\>`.

    - However, you *could* make it work with BSD/OSX `sed` by replacing `-r` with `-E`, and `\<` / `\>` with `[[:<:]]` / `[[:>:]]`